# NoMethodError: undefined method `validate_presence_of' with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. This is my very first line of RSpec and I'm already running into errors.

Bill.rb

```
class Bill
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :dollar_amount, type: Integer
  field :cent_amount, type: Integer

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :dollar_amount, presence: true
  validates :cent_amount, presence: true
end
```

bill_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Bill, type: :model do
    it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:name) }
end
```

As far as I can tell, I did include validate_presence_of in my `bill` model. In fact, I am taking it exactly from the [mongoid-Rspec doc](https://github.com/mongoid-rspec/mongoid-rspec/blob/master/README.md) 
What's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the old style of validation. Try this:

```
validates :name,
  presence: true
```

The `validates` method is much more flexible than the old specific ones and should be used in new applications. [The documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/validation.html) implies that both forms are supported, but the newer one should be encouraged.

Comment: Hi @tadman, thanks for the  stylistic suggestions! I changed it in my code. The reason why the class isn't inherited anything is because I am using mongoDB as the database, and with that I skipped active record when I created this project

Comment: Yeah, I just caught that. It looked very ActiveRecord-y. I'd make sure your test is calling the correct method. Normally testing that a particular method is triggered is way too specific. Instead look for the right side-effects, like the model being valid.